# Delphi & SmartCards

Tags: delphi, authentication, smartcard, digital-certificate

Does anyone have experience integrating SmartCard authentication in their Win32 apps? If so, are there any preferred libraries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [SecureBlackbox](http://www.eldos.com/sbb/delphi-pki.php), A component that works fine for me, a second choice can be
 [Delphi PC/SC SmartCard Component 0.91](http://www.vclcomponents.com/go/37859/373536343e37343033613b663266366136613660306636313630336137653236326537333e32356232663e313632366136313738343136653733376137303230363637333f30343137613f333265366437363632/).

try

Answer (score 2):

Well I guess that you have an SmartCard reader ... if so (and if you don't have one I don't know how you are going to manage this) then it must have some interface, RS232, USB, TCP/IP ... any one will do.

Communication protocol usually is available at SmartCard reader manufacturer. Few lines, and you will have it working in Delphi.

Answer (score 1):

You need to read the developer manual that comes with reader you're going to use. It might only use PC-SC (by MS) to communicate, if so you can use the component specified by RRUZ, however it doesn't work with D2009. Otherwise you'll need to use API provided by SDK.